# Error en conversión de un objeto de tipo 'System.DBNull' al tipo 'System.Byte[]'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Tengo una tabla llamada concurso cuyo campo primario es Idconcurso que es un campo de tipo varchar(50) (No Null) , razón por la cual dentro del desarrollo lo considero como un campo String

Codigo Aspx del campo ()que esta dentro de una grilla y que es un hpervinculo para que se abra un archivo en PDF:

```
<asp:CommandField ControlStyle-CssClass="GrvSelection" SelectText="Pinrecesc" 
   ShowSelectButton="True" HeaderText="Pin_o_recibo_escaneado">
    <ControlStyle CssClass="GrvSelection"> </ControlStyle>
</asp:CommandField>
```

Este es el código C#:

```
protected void gvContact6_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   string Idconcurso = Convert.ToString(gvContact6.DataKeys[gvContact6.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString());
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();                                                                                                                       
SqlDataAdapter DA3;

DA3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from concurso where Idconcurso = + Idconcurso", sqlCon6);

DA3.Fill(dtbl);

    if (dtbl != null)
      {
      DataTable DT3 = new DataTable();
      SqlDataAdapter DAN;
      DAN = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM concurso where Idconcurso= +  
      Idconcurso", sqlCon6);
      DAN.Fill(DT3);

     if (DT3 != null)
     {
      Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
      Stream Str1 = new MemoryStream((byte[])DT3.Rows[0]["Pinrecesc"]);  /*Aquí esta el error */
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int SecuenciaByte = Str1.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
      while (SecuenciaByte > 0)
       {
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, SecuenciaByte); 
        SecuenciaByte = Str1.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }  
     }
    }
  }
```

El error que me aparece es:

> Excepción no controlada por el usuario

> System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo >'System.DBNull' al tipo 'System.Byte[]'.'

Vale mencionar que la línea de código:

```
Stream Str1 = new MemoryStream((byte[])DT3.Rows[0]["Pinrecesc"]);
```

Y todo el desarrollo funciona bien cuando el desarrollo lo tengo con el campo **Idconcurso** como tipo entero.

Muchas gracias por la colaboración!.

Comment: para validar un string en una consulta Sql tienes que encerrarlas con comilla simple, "SELECT * FROM concurso where Idconcurso= '"  +  Idconcurso + "'"

Answer (score 0):

Lo que observo es que realizas dos veces la misma consulta a la tabla `concurso` filtrando por el `Idconcurso`

Tienes que validar si el campo no esta en null usando un `if` con el `DBNull.Value`

Ademas tienes que usar parametros, concatenar en un string el valor es una pesima practica

Podria ser algo como esto

```
protected void gvContact6_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    string Idconcurso = Convert.ToString(gvContact6.DataKeys[gvContact6.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString());

    string query = "select * from concurso where Idconcurso = @Idconcurso";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon6);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idconcurso", Idconcurso);
    var DA3 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();  
    DA3.Fill(dtbl);

    if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 0)
        return;

    if(dtbl.Rows[0]["Pinrecesc"] == DBNull.Value)
        return;

    var Pinrecesc = (byte[])dtbl.Rows[0]["Pinrecesc"];
    
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(Pinrecesc);
    
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
     
}
```

Comment: Pero pese a que tengo definida la variable escalar en  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idconcurso", Idconcurso ,
Y he definido  DT3 como : DataTable DT3 = new DataTable

 me muestra el siguiente error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Debe declarar la variable escalar "@Idconcurso".'

Comment: Disculpa edite el codigo, me falto cambiar el parametro en la linea `var DA3 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);` donde hay que pasarle el objeto command por parametro

Comment: Muchas gracias , lo que pasa es que me aparece el siguiente error cuando ejecuto el programa , me marca la linea de código  if (DT3.Rows[0]["Pinrecesc"] == DBNull.Value) y el error dice Excepción no controlada por el usuario --System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'No hay ninguna fila en la posición 0.' no entiendo por que mostrara ese error debido a que el registro seleccionado me trae registros.

Comment: Pusiste el `if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 0)` ? porque eso no deberia dejarte pasar sino hay rows. Si trae registro no puede dar ese error

Comment: un detalle estas usando `dtbl` no `DT3`, tiene que ser `dtbl.Rows[0]["Pinrecesc"]`

Comment: Muchas gracias, Leandro todo salió a la perfección, cordial saludo enviare carta de agradecimiento al medio que usted desee, Saludos desde Colombia.

Comment: considera @MartínezHernán aceptar la respuesta si te ayudó!